# backbone + rails TypeError: List.Header is not a constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, constructor, coffeescript, typeerror

I am trying to follow along with the tutorial I purchased from this site: http://www.backbonerails.com/

I am following along with the 5th episode of the series, "Getting Up and Running - Part 1".

At about the 46:52 mark of the video he has this code for "list_controller.js.coffee".

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  List.Controller =

    listHeader: ->
      console.log "header"
```

When I have this...everything works...the console reads "header".

At about the 47:20 mark of the video he changes it to this:

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  List.Controller =

    listHeader: ->   
      headerView = @getHeaderView()
      App.headerRegion.show headerView

    getHeaderView: ->
      new List.Header
```

When he changes the code, I am supposed to be able to see the header in my browser, but I don't. In firebug, I get the error:

```
TypeError: List.Header is not a constructor 
  return new List.Header;
```

The other relevant code is here:

list_header.jst.eco

```
<div id="header" class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <span class="brand">Backbone Poop</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

list_view.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class List.Header extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "header/list/templates/list_header"
```

header_app.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp", (HeaderApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  @startWithParent = false

  API =

    listHeader: ->
      HeaderApp.List.Controller.listHeader()

  HeaderApp.on "start", ->
    API.listHeader()
```

**UPDATE**

So I was messing around with the code...don't think I changed anything...but I got the console message, "header", to appear again. But now firebug says:

```
uncaught exception: Template undefined not found!
```

I've checked to make sure all of my path stuff with the directory structure is correct, couldn't see any problems. Any ideas?

**MORE INFO**

I get the same error in chrome's console. But when I inspect the error (click the arrow) and scroll to the (undefined function) and click its corresponding "app.js:14" link...I can see this:

```
App.addInitializer(function() {
  App.module("HeaderApp").start();
  return App.module("FooterApp").start();
});
```

It looks the "HeaderApp" isn't getting returned...important?

Comment: Can you try to replace `new List.Header` with `new List.Header()` and also tell me what is the output of this?

Comment: did you see my update?

Comment: Yes I did, can't help anymore, sorry.

Comment: You're using rails right? Can you show the file with you're #= require lines?

Comment: hey marc...i have since moved on to a new project (learning javascript/html/css) from the ground up...as I was told that it is better to learn that way then through copy/paste programming...cheers for the response though