# Template undefined not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, coffeescript, uncaught-exception

Hi I am working on a tutorial, and extending a question I had here - [backbone + rails TypeError: List.Header is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820407/backbone-rails-typeerror-list-header-is-not-a-constructor)

I fixed the problem that I originally had in the old question, however I have a new error (which I see in the chrome console):

```
uncaught exception: Template undefined not found!
```

A similar message happens in the firebug console too.

Not only do I get this error, but now the "header" message doesn't get displayed in the console - and neither the footer nor the header are visible on the page (before I could at least see the footer).

list_controller.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  List.Controller =

    listHeader: ->
      console.log "header"
      headerView = @getHeaderView()
      App.headerRegion.show headerView

    getHeaderView: ->
      new List.Header
```

list_view.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class List.Header extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "header/list/templates/list_header"
```

header_app.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp", (HeaderApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  @startWithParent = false

  API =

    listHeader: ->
      HeaderApp.List.Controller.listHeader()

  HeaderApp.on "start", ->
    API.listHeader()
```

list_header.jst.eco

```
<div id="header" class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <span class="brand">Backbone Poop</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the file where the error is defined:

backbone/config/marionette/renderer.js.coffee

```
Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = (template, data) ->
  path = JST["backbone/apps/" + template]
  unless path
    throw "Template #{template} not found!"
  path(data)
```

I commented all of the above lines out (removing the file essentially) - and I get the error (chrome console):

```
Uncaught TemplateNotFoundError: Cannot render the template since it's false, null or undefined.
```

Could it have something to do with the "path" variable? HeaderApp and FooterApp are both in the folders "header" and "footer", under the directory: app/assets/javascripts/backbone/apps

Comment: I don't work on Rails but this might help  http://www.backbonerails.com/

Comment: thanks guys...i have since abandoned this project...im looking more into javascript/html basics as I was told that is what I should start with